# Decrypt DynamoDB Stream using DynamoDB Encryption Client (Item Encryptor)?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I encrypted records using DynamoDB Encryption Client (Item Encryptor) ([Lib Link](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-dynamodb-encryption-docs)). Now I want to decrypt it. I've read the docs and GitHub page, there is no example so it's really hard to figure out what part I got wrong.

This is the "NewImage" from DynamoDB event. The key is "ID".
[DynamoDB Stream Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPPpG.png)

I've tried:

- Using `decrypt_dynamodb_item` -> not working

```
"errorMessage": "Invalid material description",
"errorType": "InvalidMaterialDescriptionError",
```

- Convert the "NewImage" to ddb type using `ddb_to_dict` then using `decrypt_dynamodb_item`-> not working

```
"errorMessage": "Value must be of the following types: <class 'bytearray'>, <class 'bytes'>.",
"errorType": "TypeError",
```

- Get the record directly from the table using `get_item` (instead of using the DynamoDB Stream event) and decrypt it using `decrypt_python_item`. And, it worked -> So I'm pretty sure my `cryto_config` is right. The record configuration which I get directly from the table:
  [DynamoDB Get_Item Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INGMv.png)

Do anyone know how to decrypt DynamoDB Stream using DynamoDB Encryption Client. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I was able to get the item when I called **query**() using DDB Mapper but was not able to do so using **marshallIntoObject**() on the DynamoDB stream.

The issue was that the binary attributes in the Dynamo DB stream are encoded in Base64. They need to be decoded first before being passed to the API.